# overriding Content-Type cause Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ios, apache, curl, http-headers

I am doing an iOS app and I require to set Content-Type headers by my own.

Whenever I override the HTTP header the web server returns 500 - Internal server error.

So I tried with a PHP code to check whether this is iOS or server side error.

```
    $target_url = 'http://myserver.com';
    $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('8.jpeg');
    $post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--xxx"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
```

The above code response with Internal Server Error.

but whenever I remove bellow line, it works fine.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--xxx"));
```

At last I tried to re-generate the issue with Chrome Postman plugin. I got the same result. If I set `Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data` I ended up having the same issue.

Is there anything to do with apache or php configurations to accept overriding headers?

Appreciate any clue on fixing this issue.

Comment: Check your server error logs.

Comment: I contacted the server admin and he said there is no error recorded. I am in really confused situation.

Comment: Try turnning the PHP errors on. Add `in_set(display_errors,1);` on top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a parameter as `param => @/test/file.txt` it uses the multipart file upload by default. So when you alter this, you get error.

You can only alter the Header(without any error) only if you remove the file uploading parameter.